# Maintaining Parent and Child projects together

Tags: git

I have a git repo `my-custom-framework`. In this repo, I maintain my framework which I use to create lots of projects. Everytime I have a new project, I clone this repository to something `my-project-repo`.

What I want to do is, while working on `my-project-repo`; I make some changes which I also want to be merged in to parent repo `my-custom-framework`. And vice versa. I also have to make sure that any project specific changes do not merge into the parent repository.

What would be the best way to achieve this. I tried Googling; but articles like `submodules` appear; which I don't think would solve my problem.

Comment: What kind of framework is `my-custom-framework`?  A bunch of HTML files, boilerplate code, runnable code, what?

Comment: It is PHP CodeIgnitor framework, with some basic working project (like a simple survey system) and third-party libraries via composer, bower and a RESTful API

Answer (score 0):

you could use the environment variable GIT_DIR.

```
cd path/to/subproject
set GIT_DIR=path/to/superproject
git rev-parse --git-dir
git commit 
set GIT_DIR=
```

see 'git help git'